# How to select multiple elements that are children of given element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have `<div id='mydiv'>` and I need to select all `pre` and `div` elements that are children of `#mydiv`.

I could do it this way:

```
div#mydiv > pre, div#mydiv > div
```

but, can it be done so that `#mydiv` is referenced only once?

```
div#mydiv > pre, div
```

will select all `div`s on the page regardless if they're children of `#mydiv`,  so the comma isn't a way to do it. Maybe there's another kind of syntax I don't know about?

Comment: that's it ... there's no other way

Comment: Well you don't need `div` at the beginning of your selector...

Comment: W3C, Why U NO `parent > (child1, .., childN)` ?!!? /@~@/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You'll have to reference `#mydiv` twice...

```
#mydiv > pre, #mydiv > div
```

I removed the extraneous `div` element selector as the ID is specific enough.

Comment: agree with removing the div qualifier, but I don't see jQuery mentioned in the question or tags - maybe just write it as CSS?

Comment: Saved my day. It is how works. :)

Answer (score 29):

You can actually group selectors with `:is()`.

So in your case you would use it like this:

```
div#mydiv > :is(pre, div) {
     // CSS
}
```

Here is the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

Comment: Cool, but be warned that this has fairly low browser support.

Comment: This now has full browser support and is very useful, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there is no shorthand for selector grouping.

See "[Selector Grouping](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorgrouping)".

Although, with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), it is possible in the "Nested Rules" section.

Comment: This is the kind of case that LESS is designed to handle, it seems

Answer (score 7):

The only way to reference the id only once is to use it with the `*` selector:

```
#mydiv > * {
```

which will apply to *all* elements that are children of that div.

Depending on what styles you plan to apply this might be workable (I typically use this to zero-out margins, padding and border styles), but it's still probably best to do it the first way because it makes it easier to make exceptions/changes later down the road.