# Apply CSS to one form

Tags: html, css

In a larger application, we'd like to shrink many elements of a single form `quickpost-form`

```
 <div id="qp-form">
```

There are several elements of the form that need to have smaller font.  For example, `text`, `input`, `input-group`, `textarea`.  At first I tried this .css:

```
#qp-form label, text, input, input-group, textarea
```

This works, but actually changed the sizes of these fields across forms.  Realized that the comma foregoes inheritance, so instead tried the following based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192596/how-to-select-multiple-elements-that-are-children-of-given-element).

```
#qp-form > label, #qp-form > text, #qp-form > input
```

But this did not correctly change the font-sizes (they were not applied).

**What is the most succinct/typical way to change various inputs across a single form?**  I've also tried the following:

```
.qp-form label text input input-group select textarea
```

Comment: The comma separated rule you posted *could* work, but it depends on your HTML which you didn't post. Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: As @chazsolo supposes in that answer, `#qp-form > label` only affects `label` when it is a direct, immediate _child_ of `#qp-form`. If your structure has anything like `<form id="qp-form"> ... <div class="ctrl-group"> ... <label for="X">...</label> (etc)` then _label_ is a _descendent_ but not a _child_ of `#qp-form`. A child selector uses `>` as `#qp-form > label` but a _descendent_ selector uses a space like `#qp-form label`

Comment: What are `text` and `#qp-form > text` in your CSS (?) There is no HTML element `<text>`.

Comment: Thank you @Rounin - I was trying to reference `<input type="text"` which I think is unneccessary.  Thanks - I took this out and it seemed superfulous.

Comment: No worries. If you want to select `<input type="text">` then the CSS syntax you need is `input[type="text"]`. (This is called _attribute selection_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing your HTML structure I can only assume that the elements you are targeting are not direct descendants of `#qp-form` which is why your third example with the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) didn't work.

You need to preface each selector with `#qp-form` and only use spaces to separate the elements ([descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)), further separating each group with a comma:

```css
#qp-form label,
#qp-form input,
#qp-form textarea {
  /* styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks you - yes that was exactly it.  I didn't realize the difference between child and descendant.

Comment: Another option would be to use a preprocessor like SASS and nest your values. If you are more comfortable in vanilla CSS then this is a great way too!

Comment: Thanks Calvin I'll look into SASS eventually, still pretty new to it all.