# Applying CSS rule to multiple class inside a class

Tags: css

I am trying to refactor this piece of CSS code using commas so I am not duplicating the same set of rules for every elements. Here I want specific children elements of `.clear` to be invisible when the class `.clear.` is toggled.

```
    .clear select {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }

    .clear input {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }

    .clear p {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }

    .clear .section-content {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
```

This works, but doesn't look too efficient. From my understanding, commas are used to apply the same set of rules to multiple elements.

```
    .clear select,input,p,.section-content {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
```

Now if I refactor this way, no matter if `.clear` `class` is toggled or not in my `HTML`, all element will be invisible.

What would be the correct way to make this work in one set of rules ?

Comment: You need to add the .clear class in front of every selectors, so only the classes within the .clear class is styled: .clear select, .clear input, .clear p, .clear .section-content

Comment: This seems like a rather strange choice for a duplicate question... This is a completely different question than the linked one. It does, however, seem to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192596/how-to-select-multiple-elements-that-are-children-of-given-element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192596/how-to-select-multiple-elements-that-are-children-of-given-element), you pretty much have to use `.clear` multiple times, like so:

```css
.clear select, .clear input, .clear p, .clear .section-content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Sadly, with CSS alone there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, commas are used to define [selector lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#selector_lists) against a single style block. You would need to prepend every target element with the `.clear` selector to achieve what you want:

```css
.clear select,
.clear input,
.clear p,
.clear .section-content {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

If you're looking to level-up your stylesheets, you could consider using [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide) instead to leverage nesting, meaning you could write it like this:

```
.clear {
  select,
  input,
  p,
  .section-content {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm wondering why was this downvoted. This Sass syntax does look unfamiliar. I'll try it!